# LibreOffice GUI Buttons inverted

Tags: libreoffice

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshot, after a clean installation from the official website, the gui is barely usable. I installed it on Xubuntu 16.04, but maybe I will have to switch on the normal Ubuntu. Any way to fix that?

Comment: Do you have High Contrast Mode turned on somewhere?

Comment: I just installed it and opened it, nothing changed. Installation is done through unzipping and installing the official deb files

Comment: I mean in your system settings.

Comment: It is by default I guess as I havent changed it. OpenOffice for example was ok